# Prove that a sequence of random variables is almost surely a Cauchy sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $ \left(X_{n}\right)_{n} $ be a sequence of random variables such that for any $ \varepsilon >0 $  we have:

$ \lim_{n,m\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(|X_{n}-X_{m}|>\varepsilon\right)>0 $

I want to prove that $ X_n $ has a subsequence wich is Cauchy.

So, here's what I've tried:

For any $ k $ we'll choose $ n_k $ such that for any $ n,m \geq n_k $ we have:

$ \mathbb{P}\left(|X_{n}-X_{m}|>2^{-k}\right)<2^{-k} $.

We could also choose the $ n_k$'s such that $ n_{k+1} > n_k $. So denote: $ Y_k=X_{n_k}$.

I want to show that $ (Y_k)_k $ is a cauchy sequence.

Define $ F=\limsup_{k}\left\{ |Y_{k}-Y_{k+1}|>2^{-k}\right\} =\bigcap_{n}\bigcup_{k\geq n}\left\{ |Y_{k}-Y_{k+1}|>2^{-k}\right\}  $

(This is the event which $ \left\{ |Y_{k}-Y_{k+1}|>2^{-k}\right\}  $ occurs infinitly many times).

I proved, using Borel-Cantelli Lemma, that $ \mathbb{P}\left(F\right)=0 $.

All I have left to do is to conclude that $ Y_k $ is cauchy, so it sufficies to show that the probability that $ Y_k $ is not cauchy is $ 0 $. Denote the event that $(Y_k) $ is not a Cauchy sequence as $ B $.

If I'll show that $ B\subset F $ that will finish the proof. But actually I cannot see how's this even true; Given a sequence, such that for any $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ we can find $ k\geq n $ such that $ |Y_{k+1}-Y_{k}|>2^{-k} $ dosent seem to imply that $ Y_k $ is not Cauchy.

So what can I do to conclude the desirable conclusion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed $B \subset F$ but it seems you are trying to prove that $F \subset B$...
You might find it easier to check that $F^c \subset B^c$. Namely, assuming $F^c$ means that only finitely many bad events $|Y_k-Y_{k+1}|>2^{-k}$ hold. Now given $\epsilon$ choose $k_0$ larger than the indices of all  these bad events such that also $2^{-k_0}<\epsilon$ and now you can verify $|Y_n-Y_m| <\epsilon$ for $n,m>k_0$.